How to ManifestStaticFilesStorage with django-storages, boto3 on DigitalOcean Spaces Object Storage?
Context: I am running Django==5.1.2.

I need to have cache busting for my static files on prod.
On dev, my settings are like so
STORAGES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage",
    },
    "staticfiles": {
        "BACKEND": "django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage",
    },
}
STATIC_URL = "static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")

This works as you would expect. When debug=False, django uses the hashed static files for the urls.
But on prod my settings are like so
# DigitalOcean Spaces Settings
# Ref: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-object-storage-with-django
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv("DO_SOS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv("DO_SOS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv("DO_SOS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME")
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = os.getenv("DO_SOS_ENDPOINT_URL")
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    "CacheControl": "max-age=86400",
}
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = "public-read"

STORAGES["default"]["BACKEND"] = "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage"
STORAGES["staticfiles"]["BACKEND"] = "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage"
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = (
    "s3v4"
)

AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = os.getenv("DO_SOS_CUSTOM_DOMAIN")

# Static & Media URL
STATIC_URL = f"{AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL}/static/"
MEDIA_URL = f"{AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL}/media/"

As you can see, the backend is using "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage" on prod instead of "django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage". Which is kindof my problem. Whatever static content is saved to my Digital Ocean Spaces Object Storage is not hashed. How can I configure my django project to save the hashed static files to my Spaces Object Storage?

Based on Kikito's suggestion, I updated my settings to be
STORAGES["staticfiles"]["BACKEND"] = "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3ManifestStaticStorage"

When I run
python manage.py collectstatic --no-post-process

It works just fine. Then when I run
python manage.py collectstatic

I get the following error
...
Post-processed 'admin/img/search.svg' as 'admin/img/search.7cf54ff789c6.svg'
Post-processed 'admin/img/LICENSE' as 'admin/img/LICENSE.2c54f4e1ca1c'
Post-processed 'admin/img/icon-addlink.svg' as 'admin/img/icon-addlink.073aeb1feda7.svg'
Post-processed 'admin/img/icon-alert.svg' as 'admin/img/icon-alert.034cc7d8a67f.svg'
Post-processed 'admin/img/inline-delete.svg' as 'admin/img/inline-delete.fec1b761f254.svg'
Post-processed 'admin/img/icon-yes.svg' as 'admin/img/icon-yes.d2f9f035226a.svg'
Post-processed 'admin/img/tooltag-add.svg' as 'admin/img/tooltag-add.e59d620a9742.svg'
Post-processing 'admin/css/forms.css' failed!

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 413, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 459, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 209, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 154, in collect
    raise processed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 375, in _post_process
    content = pattern.sub(converter, content)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 249, in converter
    hashed_url = self._url(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 182, in _url
    hashed_name = hashed_name_func(*args)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 425, in _stored_name
    cache_name = self.clean_name(self.hashed_name(name))
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 143, in hashed_name
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The file 'admin/css/widgets.css' could not be found with <storages.backends.s3.S3ManifestStaticStorage object at 0x7f7d2070eed0>.

Scrolling up, I can see the admin/css/forms.css and the admin/css/widgets.css got copied successfully.
Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/forms.css'
Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/widgets.css'

But when it gets down to the post processing, it fails
I do see these two files exist within the bucket. So I'm not quite sure how to get past this.

I think this code might be relevant to the problem you are trying to solve.
